emulator command on Docker
I have a Dockerfile that his goal is downloading an existing .avd file and running it on the docker image.
The problem is that I can't manage to download the emulator command. Am I missing something here?
This is the Dockerfile
# Use a base image with Java support
FROM openjdk:11-jdk

# Install necessary packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    unzip \
    libstdc++6 \
    libglu1-mesa \
    libpulse0 \
    libasound2 \
    libc6 \
    libncurses5 \
    libsdl1.2debian \
    libz1 \
    libpulse-dev \
    x11vnc \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Set up environment variables
ENV ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
ENV ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_HOME
ENV PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator

# Download and install Android SDK Command-line Tools
RUN mkdir -p ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools \
    && wget -q https://dl.google.com/android/repository/commandlinetools-linux-10406996_latest.zip -O commandlinetools.zip \
    && unzip commandlinetools.zip -d ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools \
    && mv ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/cmdline-tools ${ANDROID_HOME}/cmdline-tools/latest \
    && rm commandlinetools.zip

# Accept licenses and install necessary SDK components
RUN yes | sdkmanager --licenses \
    && sdkmanager "platform-tools" "platforms;android-35" "system-images;android-35;google_apis;x86_64"

# Download and extract emulator package
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux_x64-10696886.zip -O emulator.zip \
    && unzip emulator.zip -d ${ANDROID_HOME} \
    && rm emulator.zip

# Create .android directory
RUN mkdir -p /root/.android/avd

# Copy your existing AVD files
COPY /Mobile/Pixel.avd /root/.android/avd/Pixel.avd



Which step is going wrong?  Do you get a more specific error message?
